# prototype get inner html of multiple classes

Tags: prototypejs

I am new to prototype and finding it a lot more difficult than jquery. All i want to do is get the inner html of various classes.

```
$$('.book').each(function() {
    var msg = this.down(".information"); 
    alert(msg.innerHTML);
    //new Tip(this, msg.innerHTML, {stem: 'topLeft',  hook: { tip: 'topLeft', mouse: true }, offset: { x: 14, y: 14 }});
});
```

I'm trying to create tooltips for multiple items, but I'm not even getting the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *this* variable is not pointing to the element you're iterating over in Prototype, you have to explicitly use a parameter:

```
$$('.book').each(function(book) {
    var msg = book.down(".information"); 
    alert(msg.innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can probably prevent the extra dom work of `down()` like this:

```
$$('.book .information').each(function(book) {
  alert(book.innerHTML);
});
```

remember you also have the ability to use advanced CSS2 and CSS3 selectors in prototype like this for example:

```
$$('.book a[rel]').each(function(el) {
  alert(el.rel);
});
```

see the bottom of this page for more examples http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar